# Why after set formatter of a property binding of TextField, the json model binding becomes "oneway"?

Tags: sapui5

I'm writing an application using XML view. There is a JSON Model 'data' set on the view, when I put a text field like below, I can get the updated value from user input.

```
<TextField value="{path: 'data>/xxx'}" />
```

But if I put a formatter in the binding like below, then it's impossible to get the updated value back.

```
<TextField value="{path: 'data>/xxx',
                   formatter: 'abc.util.formatter.yyy'}" />
```

Why is that? How to use JSONModel TwoWay binding and formatter at the same time???

Comment: Just found the documentation where the solution is mentioned: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__section_N10078_N10013_N10001

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The binding mode switches to OneWay as formatters do not support bi-directional data flow, as they are used for formatting property values for the output. A TwoWay binding includes also parsing and validating input before it is written to the model. If you need this, you should use a type instead. This is the same for all model type, not only the JSONModel.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe your binding sytle is problem.
Can you try this in your index.

```
data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the binding syntax